# Disable another button once it has successfully submitted the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button

I have a form with 2 buttons: Approve and Reject.

```
<input type="button" name="Approve" value="Approve" onClick="location.href='approve.php?user=<?php echo $row['icnum'];?>&states=1'">

<input type="button" name="Reject" value="Reject" onClick="location.href='approve.php?user=<?php echo $row ['icnum'];?>&states=2'">
```

I want to disable the "Reject" button once the "Approve" button is clicked. So, the user cannot reject the form again after it has been approved.

I have tried several attempts, like:

```
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="javascript=this.disabled = true; form.submit();">
```

But this code does not work for me. Even if it's actually working, the button is just disabling itself, not the other button.

I'm using Chrome. Any idea on how to solve this?

EDIT: This is my process form in php.

```
<?php session_start();
include('../include/dbconnect.php');
$user = $_GET['user'];
$states = $_GET['states'];

if($user){
$approve = "UPDATE student SET status='$states' WHERE icnum='$user'";

$result = mysql_query($approve) or die(mysql_error());
if ($result) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "index.php"
</script>
<?php } 
    }
?>
```

What can I edit into these codes if the action is ran in the server-side?

Comment: The actions on these buttons work with `location.href` - in other words, they both seem to cause a page's reload (probably changing some server-side state as well). If that's true, your best bet is working with server-side to adjust these actions' state.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Then, how can I adjust the codes in the server-side?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the javascript= from OnClick. You only need javascript: (colon not =) for anchors' hrefs

```
<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="this.disabled=true; formName.submit();">
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
$('input[name=Approve]').click(function () {
  $('input[name=Reject]').prop({disabled: true});
});
```

Comment: How can I called this script back in the form? Does the body needs to load the script or just called it as a function?

Comment: If you're using `jQuery`, put this in script tags after you call in the jQuery.js file, or add it to an external js file and have a call to that from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSumbit_Click" onclick="btnSumbit_Click" OnClientClick="this.style.display = 'none';"/>
```